# True or false: convex function

Tags: convex-optimization

True or false: if $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a convex function, $y \in \mathbb R^n$ is such that $f(y)=\min_x f(x)$, and $z \in \mathbb R^n$ is such that $\nabla f(z)=0$, then $y=z$.

This was a question on my exam, and i answered it as 'True' while the correct answer was 'False'. I just don't see how $y \neq z$, because it is specifically mentioned that f is a convex function...

Comment: Take $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Michael ohhh i see what you mean... yeah that can be true..

Comment: @Michael This got me wondering: would the statement be true if $f$ was strictly convex?

Comment: Yes. A convex function can have more than one minimizer, but a strictly convex function can have at most one minimizer.